# pandas: return first N rows of each secondary index of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've googled and searched through Stack but cannot find an answer to what would seem like this simple question:

Say I have a pandas multi-indexed dataframe as follows:

```
Foo  0    0.021362
     1    0.917947
     2   -0.956313
     3    0.834556
     4   -0.387533
Bar  0   -0.242659
     1    0.398657
     2    0.455909
     3    0.200061
     4   -1.273537
Baz  0    0.747849
     1   -0.012899
     2    1.026659
     3   -0.256648
     4    0.799381
```

How can I limit output to only the first N number of rows of each second level index as follows (if N was 2):

```
Foo  0    0.021362
     1    0.917947
Bar  0   -0.242659
     1    0.398657
Baz  0    0.747849
     1   -0.012899
```

All attempts at iloc, loc, slice, sliceindex, and ix have thus far failed. Please help and apologies if this has been posted already.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `level=0` (to group on the first index level) and call [`head(2)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) to get the first 2 rows for each group:

```
In [13]:
df.groupby(level=0).head(2)

Out[13]:
                    val
index1 index2          
Foo    0       0.021362
       1       0.917947
Bar    0      -0.242659
       1       0.398657
Baz    0       0.747849
       1      -0.012899
```

It's possible to use `loc` to slice but the index needs to be [`sorted first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
In [25]:
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.sort_index().loc[idx[:,0:1],:]

Out[25]:
                    val
index1 index2          
Bar    0      -0.242659
       1       0.398657
Baz    0       0.747849
       1      -0.012899
Foo    0       0.021362
       1       0.917947
```

without the call to `sort_index` it'll raise a `KeyError`:

> KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted
>   tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'

Comment: This is an amazing and elegant answer. I've been struggling for 2 days trying to get this functionality. I was trying to use `.groupby` with `.nth` to no avail.